# How do I dynamically update a web page from the server in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming

This seems like it should be simple (and maybe it is), but I can't seem to figure it out.
I'm trying to write a Watson application in Meteor that inserts documents into a corpus.  I want to update the client web page with the name of each document as it is inserted.  I figured the easiest way to update the web page would be to add a template with {{each}} that iterates through a Collection. I could then just update the Collection on the server as I insert the documents.

Apparently I don't understand how this works though. Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<template name="results">
    <table border=0>
        {{#each result}}
            <tr><td>{{label}}</td></tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </template>
```

This is the helper for the template:

```
Template.results.helpers({
    "result":function()
        {
        return addedDocs.find();
        }
    })
```

At the top of the .js file, outside of everything else, is

```
var addedDocs=new Mongo.Collection("added");
```

which should make *addedDocs* a global variable.

The server code is in another file, in the ***server/*** directory. In the loop which adds the documents, I have

```
addedDocs.insert(doc.label);
```

which should insert a new mongoDB record for each document as it's added to the corpus.

My understanding is that this should all work and the document names should magically appear on the web page as they are added.  Problem is, it won't even compile like this.  I think it has to do with the fact that the server and client code are in separate .js files.  As it is, I get the error

```
Exception while invoking method 'buildCorpus' ReferenceError: addedDocs is not defined
```

on the server, which of course means that I need to define the addedDocs variable in the server .js file too.  But *nooooo*, when I define the collection variable on the server

```
var addedDocs=new Mongo.Collection("added");
```

I get this error instead:

```
Error: A method named '/added/insert' is already defined
W20150709-14:19:59.386(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461:1
W20150709-14:19:59.386(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20150709-14:19:59.386(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
W20150709-14:19:59.386(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
W20150709-14:19:59.387(-5)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:209:1)
W20150709-14:19:59.387(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/ciCorpusBuilder.js:3:15
W20150709-14:19:59.396(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/ciCorpusBuilder.js:297:3
W20150709-14:19:59.396(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/david/workspaces/javascript/CI_CorpusBuilder/src/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150709-14:19:59.396(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150709-14:19:59.396(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/david/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

I get similar errors on the client if I define the collection in the server file but not in the client file.

Am I just going about this all wrong?  Is there a better way? What am I missing here?  I'm pulling out my hair!

Comment: Have you tried declaring it in a separate .js file in the root folder where both server and client have access?

Comment: `var addedDocs=new Mongo.Collection("added");` creates a local variable in that file. Remove the `var` to make `addedDocs` global.

Comment: @mutil @MichelFloyd I tried removing the `var` but the compiler complained because I was using the `"use strict"` directive.  Putting the `var addedDocs=new Mongo.Collection("added");` line in a common shared file didn't change the errors I was getting.  Doing **both** seems to have fixed the problem though!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consolidating what was said in the comments:

1. You should declare your collections as global variables - those without the `var`
2. The collections needs to be accessible from both the server and the client, and this means you should place it in a separate top-level directory like `common/` or `lib/`